# Cannot Detect Alt-beacon in android

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I am using Radius networks altbeacon library in my android app , but whenever i broadcast altbeacon from locate app , my app cant detect the altbeacon .

This is my beacon parser :-

```
 mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```

This is my ANDROID STUDIO LOGCAT :-

```
06-11 11:43:45.239 15797-16636/optimus.com.optimusiothome D/BeaconParser:Ignoring pdu type 01
06-11 11:43:45.239 15797-16636/optimus.com.optimusiothome D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c0002152f234454cf6d4a0fadf2f4911ba9ffa600000000c50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
06-11 11:43:45.239 15797-16636/optimus.com.optimusiothome D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c0002152f234454cf6d4a0fadf2f4911ba9ffa600000000c50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

whenever i transmit altbeacon from locate app in my iphone  the below code is printed in logcat many times for my android app  , but the main concern is , didRangeBeaconsInRegion() function is never called , and my code in the function is not executed i.e my android app cant detect altbeacon ( transmitting from locate app in myiphone ):-

```
06-11 11:44:38.669 18053-18072/optimus.com.optimusiothome D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
06-11 11:44:38.669 18053-18072/optimus.com.optimusiothome D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID
06-11 11:44:38.669 18053-18072/optimus.com.optimusiothome D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=69:86:DE:DD:64:1D, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=26, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, 47, 35, 68, 84, -49, 109, 74, 15, -83, -14, -12, -111, 27, -87, -1, -90, 0, 0, 0, 0, -59]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-55, mTimestampNanos=97773873478375}
```

And I am Using following dependency in android gradle :-

```
compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.7'
```

Some more code :-

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
       Region region = new Region("all-beacon-region",null,null,null);
    // this tells the library that we want to know about any beacon we see.
    try {
        mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //The last line sets the rangeNotifier to this class,
    //so our the same RangingActivity class will get callbacks each time a beacon is seen.
    mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
}

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
    for(Beacon beacon : collection)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Beacon detected with id1: " + beacon.getId1() + " id2:" + beacon.getId2() + " id3: " + beacon.getId3() + " distance: " + beacon.getDistance());
        ((TextView)beacon_transmit_detect.this.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText("Beacon detected with id1: " + beacon.getId1() + " id2:" + beacon.getId2() + " id3: " + beacon.getId3() + " distance: " + beacon.getDistance());

    }
}



@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mBeaconManager=BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
 mBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }
```

And my main class implements  BeaconConsumer,RangeNotifier .

Comment: Are you sure you have altbeacon selected on the transmitter side of Locate?  The logs suggest your app is transmitting iBeacon.  Do you have more than one beacon around?

Comment: sir through which parameter you decided that my app is transmitting ibeacon .... and my issue is resolved i had to add ibeacon parser in the code ...and one more thing sir , does locate app on my iphone , we see different beacon types to transmit , does all trasmit ibeacon , because when i was transmitting radius networks beacon from the app i had to add ibeacon parser to detect it , isn't the radius networks beacon (altbeacon ) different from ibeacon .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the main beacon layouts
Check if your layout is a correct one.

ALTBEACON "m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"

EDDYSTONE TLM "x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"

EDDYSTONE UID "s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"

EDDYSTONE URL "s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"

IBEACON "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"

A reference list here.